# Limitar accesso em areas do app para diferentes usuarios

Tags: java, android, permissões

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de app para uma empresa e acabei entrando em um problema que não encontrei como saná-lo.

Gostaria de limitar acesso a certas partes do app para diferentes usuários.

**Ex.:** gostaria que os administradores da empresa com seus logins vissem coisas no app que funcionários, com seus logins, não conseguissem ver.

- Permitir páginas exclusivas apenas a administradores, fazendo com que outros usuários não possam acessar.

Estou utilizando **Firebase** e **Android Studio**, gostaria de saber se há uma classe ou API para isso.

Comment: Você pode utilizar a lógica do nosso amigo Edson Reis, não tenho conhecimento de desenvolvimento Android, porém normalmente para permissões é feito dessa forma que ele citou. Outra maneira bacana é você criar uma classe que irá realizar o controle das páginas por nível de usuário, dentro você pode colocar um `switch case` que checa irá retornar um `array` ou outros valores autorizando ou não o acesso. Você poderia retornar um `boolean` e jogar todas as páginas de admin dentro de um array por exemplo. Então basta verificar no switch case se administradores tem acesso a determinada página.

Comment: Resolvi não responder a sua pergunta com um exemplo, pois por não entender de programação Android pode não ser o que você espera.

Comment: Resumindo, faça um método: `private Boolean checaAcessoPagina(String nivelPermissao){}` - dentro do método use um `switch case(nivelPermissao)` para diferenciar os níveis, pode ser "admin, user, visitor, etc". Aí agora é com você, apenas uma sugestão mais prática.

Comment: Veja esta discussão (não sei se posso postar links externos aqui): http://respostas.guj.com.br/1529-controle-de-acesso-com-android

Answer (score 1):

1.Você tem que ter value que defina quem é admin ou usuário no seu banco de usuários.
Exemplo: nivel = "admin"
         nivel = "funcionario"

2. Voce pode usar o Realtime Database Firebase. para criar um novo user. 
   Exemplo.

   ```
   private void writeNewUserIfNeeded(final String userId, final String username, final String name) {
   final DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId);

   usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if (!dataSnapshot.exists())
               usersRef.setValue(new User(username, name));
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
   ```

   }

3.A cada chamada da tela que queira limitar para o nível de usuário você 
tem que fazer uma condição. Exemplo:

```
       if(user.nivel.equals("admin")){

        //ABRIR A TELA PARA ADMIN
        }else{
        // BLOQUEADO! 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia adicionar condições de visualização, por exemplo:

Ao fazer login o método retornaria o grupo no qual aquele usuário pertenceria

```
public GrupoDeUsuario autenticar(usuario, senha){

} 

boolean isAdm = GrupoDeUsuario.Administrador;
```

Nas suas Views você poderia checar e só mostrar a View se fosse para o grupo de interesse

```
btnAcessoPeloAdm = findViewByID(R.id.btnAdm);
btnAcessoPeloAdm.setVisibility(isAdm ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```